WPF eventually freezes even when scanning ports from async tasks
I am writing a port scanner and unable to create fluid UI.
I have a DataGrid that display scanning results:
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding NetScanResults}" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">

Then I have an object that holds scan result.
public class NetScanResult : ObservableObject
{
    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    public IPAddress IpAddress
    {
        get => ipAddress;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref ipAddress, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpAddressStr));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<int> openPorts;
    public ObservableCollection<int> OpenPorts
    {
        get => openPorts;
        set { SetProperty(ref openPorts, value); }
    }

    public NetScanResult()
    {
        OpenPorts = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }
}

And finally I have a scanning logic:
[RelayCommand]
public async void NetScan2Start()
{
    try
    {
        int[] ports = { 22, 80, 443, 554, 3389, 8000, 37777 };
        int timeoutMs = 2500;

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var netScanResults = await NetUtility.ScanNetwork2_Prepare(NetScanIpRangeBegin, NetScanIpRangeEnd, NetScanNetmaskSelected, ports, timeoutMs);
        NetScanResults = new ObservableCollection<NetScanResult>(netScanResults);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var netScanResult in NetScanResults)
        {
            foreach (var port in ports)
            {
                NetScanResult tempResult = netScanResult;
                int tempPort = port;

                var task = ScanPortAsync(tempResult, tempPort, timeoutMs);

                tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

        stopwatch.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show($"Scan finished in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowInvalidData(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}


private async Task ScanPortAsync(NetScanResult result, int port, int timeoutMs)
{
    try
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        var connectResult = socket.BeginConnect(result.IpAddress, port, null, null);

        await Task.Run(() => { connectResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMs, true); });

        if (socket.Connected)
        {
            socket.EndConnect(connectResult);

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                result.OpenPorts.Add(port);
            });
            
            Debug.WriteLine($"{result.IpAddress}:{port} - open.");
        }

        socket.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($" Exception happened =( - {ex.Message}");
    } 
}

I starts smoothly but after some time UI still freezes and I don't understand why.
It unfreezes when all scanning thread are finished.
What am I missing?
Update:
I've modified my code and implement your suggestions.
private int progressStep;
private int progress;
private int progressTotal;
private DispatcherTimer progressTimer;

[RelayCommand]
public async void NetScan3Start() => await Task.Run(async () =>
{

    int[] ports = { 22, 80, 443, 554, 3389, 8000, 37777 };
    int timeoutMs = 250;

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    IList<IPAddress> addresses = await NetUtility.ScanNetwork2_Prepare(NetScanIpRangeBegin, NetScanIpRangeEnd, NetScanNetmaskSelected);

    //
    var list = new List<NetScanResult2>();

    foreach (var address in addresses)
    {
        list.Add(new NetScanResult2(address));
    }

    progressTotal = list.Count * ports.Length;
    progressStep = (int)(list.Count * ports.Length * 0.05); //5% of total amount;
    progress = 0;

    _ = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        NetScanResults = new ObservableCollection<NetScanResult2>(list);
    }));

    progressTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
    progressTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    progressTimer.Tick += ProgressTimer_Tick;
    progressTimer.Start();
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;


    //
    var scanTasks = new List<Task>();

    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5);

    foreach (var netScanResult in list)
    {
        var tmpNetScanResult = netScanResult;
        var tmpAddress = netScanResult.IpAddress;

        foreach (var port in ports)
        {
            var tmpPort = port;

            var scanTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();

                try
                {
                    var client = new TcpClient();

                    var connectTask = client.ConnectAsync(tmpAddress, tmpPort);
                    var delayTask = Task.Delay(timeoutMs);

                    var result = await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, delayTask);

                    if (result == connectTask && client.Connected)
                    {
                        _ = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            tmpNetScanResult.OpenPorts.Add(tmpPort);
                        }));
                    }

                    client.Dispose();
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    ++progress;
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
            });

            scanTasks.Add(scanTask);
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(scanTasks);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    progressTimer.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show($"Finished in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
});

private void ProgressTimer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NetScanAmount = progressTotal - progress;
}

I've implemented a timer to show progress and also simplified the port scanning code.
Adding a semaphore to limit the number of simultaneous scanning tasks to 5 and switching to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke for UI updates has somewhat reduced the UI freezing issues, but not entirely. However, it also significantly increased the time it takes to complete all the scans.
I am also seeing a lot of Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll and Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll in Debug output which is strange because there is a try-catch block around ConnectAsync method - I thought that maybe these exceptions could also slow down the application.
If I remove the semaphore or increase it limit from 5 to 7 or greater number, the UI becomes almost non-responsive but sometimes manages to show some updates.
I am running this on Intel i5-1135g7 cpu if it matters.
Still trying to understand the source of UI freezes.

Break the debugger when the UI freezes. Select the main thread in the Threads window. Look at the line it's stuck on.

You're also spinning up a lot of parallel tasks there. That's almost certainly a horribly inefficient thing to do: the ThreadPool will keep adding threads over time, and you'll get more and more scans all trying to happen at the same time. You probably want to have a small number of threads (one per CPU ish?) all running at full speed

You're also using the UI thread to marshal results back into result.OpenPorts. Chances are that that's what's freezing the UI? You're getting so many results that the UI's just tied up processing thousands of "Add another item to result.OpenPorts" requests. But, the debugger will tell you for sure

@canton7 i've tried to comment out Dispatcher.Invoke call but the UI still freezes.
I've tried querying jobs to ThreadPool but the amount of time it take to complete scans is almost the same. Thank you nevertheless .

I use Ping if I'm just "scanning ports" before attempting a connection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-8.0

Having a setter on a ObservableCollection type is definitely a bad practice, as everyone that subscribed to the previous instance will still keep it alive, and they won't be subscribed to the right (current) object.

Even if you are creating multiple tasks, they will all be executed on the main thread. The only point when you leave the main thread is inside the lambda of Task.Run. after the await however You're still on the UI thread (due to the dispatcher synchronization context associated to the main thread). If your goal was to use the thread pool, consider a Task.Run(() => ScanPortAsync(..)). Also Dispatcher.Invoke is a synchronous blocking call, maybe you can use await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()

@FedericoAlterio I must have understood Task.Run in a wrong way. I thought it executes on the background thread. I thought that it would execute blocking port scanning (with timeout) in a background thread and call the dispatcher when finished only to display a result, which should be fast enough.

@FedericoAlterio the problem is that it still hangs UI thread even without calling the dispatcher. I just can't understand how the process of creating multiple background threads could still freeze the UI - they are supposed to be background.

Yes Task.Run() make thing shappen in a different thread (A threadpool one),but you are still are handling all the remaining work on the UI. For example: "socket.BeginConnect" happens on the UI, and also "socket.EndConnect(connectResult)". Also, Dispatcher.Invoke() makes no sense there since you already are on the UI Thread."connectResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne" isntead is not happening on the UI Thread, and that is good. But maybe all the remaining code is still enough to block-ish the UI. Maybe you can force the full method to run on a different thread with task.Run(() => ScanPortAsync(..))

I didn't see from your code why you used ObservableCollection. You don't have any changes to these collections anywhere. You form them completely and only then return them. In my opinion, it is quite possible to use a "read-only" collection here.
I also don't see any need for mutable properties, using Dispatcher, or other nuances. The scan result is assigned to something incomprehensible - it is actually sent to the trash. Synchronous and asynchronous code are mixed in an unimaginable way.
I would advise you to radically change your approach to implementing your task.
Take a look at this example - since you haven't shown all the code related to your implementation, the example is based on guesswork and may not be entirely accurate:
    public class NetScanResult : ObservableObject
    {
        public IPAddress IpAddress { get; }

        public IReadOnlyList<int> OpenPorts { get; }

        public NetScanResult(IPAddress ipAddress, IEnumerable<int> openPorts)
        {
            IpAddress = ipAddress;
            OpenPorts = Array.AsReadOnly(openPorts?.ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<int>());
        }
    }

        private async Task<int> ScanPortAsync(/*NetScanResult result,*/ IPAddress ipAddress, int port, int timeoutMs)
            => await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                var connectResult = socket.BeginConnect(/*result.IpAddress,*/ipAddress, port, null, null);

                //await Task.Run(() => { connectResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMs, true); });
                connectResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMs, true);

                if (socket.Connected)
                {
                    socket.EndConnect(connectResult);

                    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    //{
                    //    result.OpenPorts.Add(port);
                    //});

                    Debug.WriteLine($"{/*result.IpAddress*/ ipAddress}:{port} - open.");
                }

                socket.Close();
                return port;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($" Exception happened =( - {ex.Message}");
                return -1;
            }
        });

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void NetScan2Start() => await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                int[] ports = { 22, 80, 443, 554, 3389, 8000, 37777 };
                int timeoutMs = 2500;

                var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();

                // I would change the method to return IP addresses.
                /*var netScanResults*/
                IList<IPAddress> addresses = await NetUtility.ScanNetwork2_Prepare(NetScanIpRangeBegin, NetScanIpRangeEnd, NetScanNetmaskSelected, ports, timeoutMs);
                //NetScanResults = new ObservableCollection<NetScanResult>(netScanResults);
                //var tasks = new List<Task>();
                var netScanTasks = new Task<NetScanResult>[addresses.Count];

                //foreach (var netScanResult in NetScanResults)
                for (int i = 0; i < addresses.Count; i++)
                {
                    var portsTasks = new Task<int>[ports.Length];
                    IPAddress tempAddress = addresses[i];

                    //foreach (var port in ports)
                    for (int j = 0; j < ports.Length; j++)
                    {
                        //NetScanResult tempResult = netScanResult;
                        int tempPort = ports[j];

                        /*var task*/
                        portsTasks[j] = ScanPortAsync(/*tempResult,*/ tempAddress, tempPort, timeoutMs);

                        //tasks.Add(task);
                    }

                    netScanTasks[i] = CreateResult();
                    async Task<NetScanResult> CreateResult()
                    {
                        await Task.WhenAll(portsTasks);
                        List<int> aports = new List<int>(ports.Length);
                        foreach (var task in portsTasks)
                        {
                            int port = task.Result;
                            if (port > 0)
                            {
                                aports.Add(port);
                            }
                        }
                        return new NetScanResult(tempAddress, aports);
                    };
                }

                await Task.WhenAll(netScanTasks);
                NetScanResults = netScanTasks.Select(task => task.Result).ToArray();

                stopwatch.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show($"Scan finished in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowInvalidData(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        });


Interesting suggestions.
I used ObservableCollection because, as I understand it, it is the standard collection to use when working with bindings. Initially, I wanted to add new items upon completion, but I found that the standard DataGrid is slow and causes the application to hang.
My ultimate goal is to update the corresponding items and display them as soon as their respective scanning tasks are finished, rather than waiting for all of them to complete and then displaying them in a single UI update.

@CorellianAle
ObservableCollection is only needed if the collection changes AFTER it was bound. Changes include adding, deleting, inserting, and replacing elements. Changes to the elements themselves (usually their properties) are not considered changes to the collection.

Have you tried any of my suggestions?
The most important thing to note is that the entire command body is wrapped in Task.Run() and there are no calls to synchronous objects (Dispatcher.Invoke) anywhere in the asynchronous code.

I've tried your approach, and it does indeed fix the UI freeze issue. Now I am working on updating elements in real-time as soon as their particular scan finishes.

@CorellianAle
If you create another topic describing this problem, I will try to find a suitable solution.
